# Printing dynamic strings from a C# application

Tags: c#, printing

I have a very simple application that retrieve some data from a SQLite db e shows them on page.
I need to print this stuff (and something else... but let's start with this)

My code looks like that:

```
 private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        string toPrint = "";

        toPrint += txtNome.Text + " " + txtCognome.Text;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(toPrint, new Font("Arial",14,FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black,100,100);


        toPrint = "Cod. Fiscale: " + txtCodFiscale.Text;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(toPrint, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 125);


        toPrint = "Email: " + txtEmail.Text;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(toPrint, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 150);


        toPrint = "Data di Nascita: " + dtpDataNascita.Value;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(toPrint, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 175);


    }
```

The app crashes almost everytime with no possibility to kill the process.
I noticed that sometimes, the first time I push the print button, it works...

**EDIT about app crash:**
Print dialog appears and I can select the printer (let's say a pdf printer) Than the "printing" message appears and nothing else happens. The program freeze, and I cannot kill its process, I only can reboot the pc.

Is there something wrong?

Thank you very much!

**IMPORTANT EDIT**
I made some tests, and I hope you'll understand this strange behaviour:
 - I run the program the first time: it works
 - I try to make a second print without exiting the program: it works
 - I exit the debug session and re-launch the program without any modifications: it freezes!!

Is there the possibility that some process is hanged or not well closed?

**EDIT Feb,18**
Here is a small video that shows the issue
[C-Sharp freezing on print](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aw5nn889cjfyskj/csharp-freeze.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: More info on `crashes` would be nice. Like the actual `exception`

Comment: Print dialog appears and I can select the printer (let's say a pdf printer)
Than the "printing" message appears and nothing else happens.
The program freeze, and I cannot kill its process, I only can reboot the pc.

Comment: Where does `printDocument1` come from? Could you show how this is created?

Comment: printDocument1 is the printDocument standard component of Visual Studio C#, and it's placed, togheter with a printDialog component, inside the webform that makes my program work

Comment: I created a new project, used exactly the code you have and it works fine. Please update your post to include either stack trace, steps to reproduce etc. for us to help you. **Edit -** did as per your edit and it still worked just fine on my end. Also could you clarify ` I exit the debug session and re-launch the program without any modifications: it freezes!` what freezes exactly, the application and or the printing does after clicking the button?

Comment: The one that freezes is the printing process.
At first I see the printer selection dialog, than, instead of showing me the filename dialog box (I'm using a pdf printer, as I told), it shows a "printing..." message box that I cannot close and that does not allow me to close the whole app.

I'll try to take a video of this behaviour

Comment: What if you choose the pdf printer as target?

Comment: Well. I tried o target a normal printer and the program do not crash.
I tried also to target the Microsoft PDF Printer... and it works.

It looks like a problem with a third party printer (Foxit PDF printer in this case...).
What a stupid issue!   :(